# Infinite direct product of C-M rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

A finite direct product of Cohen-Macaulay rings is a Cohen-Macaulay ring. It could be checked by a scrutiny into localization of a finite direct product of rings at a prime ideal of the product. Now, does the statement remain true if "finite" is replaced by "infinite"? Any leading answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not well-posed: an infinite direct product of fields is not even a noetherian ring.